# Do a action before insert products by endpoint magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, api, rest-api

I wanna make a verification before inserting products on my Magento 2.3 in the default endpoint.

**Here is a sample:**

I post a product on **rest/default/V1/products** endpoint, but I want to check if this product has stock greater than zero, or I want to change something on the product name before inserting, things like that.

What can I do to execute an action before proceeding to endpoint processing?

I've searched on so many sites and I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `catalog_product_save_before`. This event gets called for every product save action, including new products.

In order to use it you could do the following in your module:

**app\code\Vendor\Module\etc\webapi_rest\events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_before">
        <observer name="catalog_product_save_before_check_condition" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Productsaveafter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Then in `Productsaveafter` you can implement logic to connect to your own software and perform actions like adding or updating the product.

Example:

**app\code\Vendor\Module\Observer\Productsaveafter.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface{    
        
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        
        $product = $observer->getProduct();

        // Your logic to do stuff with $product       

    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, it works! Thank you!

Comment: happy to hear .. it works

Answer (score 1):

For this one you need to understand the magento flow.

1. Your above API call this service class.

   ```
    <service class="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface"
    method="save"/>
   ```
2. Now if you check respective `di.xml` file then you found that above service class call another model.

   ```
   <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository" />
   ```
3. So for your requirement, you need to check `public function save(.....)` of this file :

> Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository

so for your requirement you can create plugin of this function `public function save(.....)`

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this.

Comment: sure, If answer help you please upvote and accept as solutions, so it will help other in community.